# Is it possible to clone team (Not Member of source team) using microsoft graph api with delegated permission?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams, microsoft-graph-teams

I am able to create a new team. While trying to clone team using team Id (I am not member or owner of this team), Using Azure AD App Registration with all Required permission (Have Microsoft Graph Permission Create and delete Group or team).
But Getting access denied error while cloning team.

```
Failed to CloneTeams. StatusCode: 403, ReasonPhrase: 'Forbidden', Version: 1.1, Content: System.Net.Http.StreamContent, Headers:
{
  request-id: 7d37ee56-8aa3-44fd-83e6-d5e85fb88fab
  client-request-id: 7d37ee56-8aa3-44fd-83e6-d5e85fb88fab
  x-ms-ags-diagnostic: {"ServerInfo":{"DataCenter":"Central US","Slice":"SliceC","Ring":"4","ScaleUnit":"000","RoleInstance":"AGSFE_IN_11"}}
  Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000
  Cache-Control: private
  Date: Fri, 25 Oct 2019 07:48:09 GMT
  Content-Length: 255
  Content-Type: application/json
}
```

Comment: With delegated access permission you can only clone (or access) teams which you are member or owner of. You need to use Application Permission if you need to clone team which you don't belong to. Here is more on [this topic](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth/auth-concepts?context=graph%2Fapi%2F1.0&view=graph-rest-1.0#microsoft-graph-permissions).

Answer (score 1):

@wajeed-msft answered this in the comment above, but he's right - With delegated access permission you can only clone (or access) teams which you are member or owner of. You need to use Application Permission if you need to clone team which you don't belong to.

Why? Because this would be an escalation of privilege. If an app with delegated access could add members to other teams, it could add users to any team in the tenant without consent of the teams' owners.

Comment: @bill-bliss-msft I am performing above operations with global administrator account. Then I  am aspecting it should work cloning team. But its giving me same error